# SF universe series with unifield league of planets, some break away to go pastoral

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember which series has that -- it's SF, spans multiple books and is set in a future where there are lots of planets working together in a common unity. Some of the planets vote to leave the union and revert to (usually) pastoral settings, abandoning the high-tec available (so no more teleporters, etc). They usually end up a mess and the union has to step in again to protect the population from their own choices.

It was all in English and it's been at least a year or 5 ago that I read it. The series had several volumes and the setting is used for several different stories. I think the viewpoint was from an agent of the union.

Any clue what series that could be? The concept of a unified galaxy isn't unique enough to search really effectively.

Comment: How long ago did you read the book/s and in what language?  What viewpoint was the story narrated from?

Comment: It was all in English and it's been at least a year or 5 ago that I read it. The series had several volumes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Culture series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_series) by Iain Banks

I have only read one book in this series, but the setting sounds familiar.  To quote from the Wikipedia entry:

> Some other civilizations hold less favourable views of the Culture. At
>   the time of their war with the Culture, the Idirans and some of their
>   allies regarded the control that the Minds exercised over the Culture
>   as a form of idolatry. The Homomda regard the Culture as idealistic
>   and hyper-active. Some members of the Culture have seceded to form
>   related civilizations, known collectively as the Ulterior. These
>   include the Peace Faction, the AhForgetIt Tendency and the Zetetic
>   Elench. **Others simply drop out temporarily or permanently.**

Comment: I wondered about the Culture novels but it isn't really a theme of the novels that planets drop out and go pastoral.